# Limit circle/point of an ODE with finite eigenvalues

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, sturm-liouville-theory

Consider the following Sturm–Liouville (SL) eigenvalue problem defined in $(-\infty,0]$ or $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,+\infty)$ $$(py')'-qy=-\lambda^2wy,$$ in which $p(x)=x^2$, $w(x)=1$, and $q(x)=(x/2+a)^2+a$ with parameter $a>0$. It has a regular singularity $x=0$. We basically hope for something like homogeneous Dirichlet b.c.

It is solved by making the substitution $y(x)=e^{x/2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\lambda^2}}u(x)$, leading to Kummer's equation with two independent solutions (1st & 2nd kind) $$xu''(x)+(\gamma-x)u'(x)-\alpha u(x)=0,$$ in which $\alpha=\sqrt{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\lambda^2}-a+\frac{1}{2}$ and $\gamma=1+2\sqrt{(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\lambda^2}$.
Let's then follow the ubiquitous argument.

Requiring nondivergence at $x=0$, the 2nd kind solution is dropped. Requiring nondivergence at infinity, the 1st kind is reduced to a polynomial when $-\alpha$ is a non-negative integer and eigenvalue $\lambda^2$ is attained.
Seen from this condition for $\alpha$, *we only have a bounded and finite sequence of eigenvalues*. Therefore, one probably also expects an additional continuous spectrum. But I'm not sure whether it starts from the largest eigenvalue.

### Question

Is it possible to know the limit circle/point classification of this ODE near $0,\pm\infty$? Is the above solution useful for this purpose? How should one proceed? I also found page 13 of [this paper](http://www.math.niu.edu/SL2/papers/birk0.pdf) has a limit point/circle classification of the Kummer equation I used. Not sure if relevant.

Comment: The procedure you describe seems designed to detect the eigenvalues, but the spectrum need not consist of eigenvalues only, so there's nothing special about having only finitely many (or none at all) of these.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. It appears to me that the problem satisfies the condition for a singular SL to have an unbounded infinite sequence of discrete eigenvalues. There must be something simple that I missed. Could you please clarify a bit? Thanks.

Comment: What condition exactly are you referring to? There is no simple general condition that would give you this conclusion, and many SL problems have no eigenvalues at all (for example the free equation $-y''=\lambda y$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling What I mentioned is Atkinson's result as summarized in the 1st section of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1006/jmaa.2001.7661), but probably I misunderstood it?   
I'm not familiar with this. Let me see if I understand correctly. You mean there's no general condition or conclusion on singular SL spectrum, right? In my case, should it be finite discrete eigenvalues plus a continuous spectrum?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for your patience. A closely related issue that confuses me. What if we consider this equation on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ with homogeneous Dirichlet b.c.? The solution shown with $e^{x/2}$ doesn't seem to allow this at $+\infty$. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, the paper you quoted certainly doesn't apply to your situation because your problem isn't regular. Also, for whole line problems, you only need boundary conditions if your endpoints are in the limit circle case, and I don't think they are here (normally they aren't). If this expectation is correct, then the problem on $\mathbb R$ is essentially self-adjoint already, with no bc's.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I modified the question a little. If $\pm\infty$ are both limit points, do you have any thoughts on the singularity $x=0$? Thanks.

Comment: All the same general comments apply: the spectrum need not be discrete, and it wouldn't be surprising or unusual if it isn't.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, there's no doubt about the spectrum after hearing your previous comments and searching related materials. I just wish to know your opinion about the limit point/circle classification of the special points $0,\pm\infty$.